# Apply changes to JSPs without redeploying the application in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have application that I launch on tomcat.

Now I use `Idea` ultimate but before I used Eclipse. In `Eclipse` I change jsp content and without `tomcat` restarting these changes applyed. It was good for me.

In Idea to achieve changes I should to restart tomcat. Is there way in idea to apply jsp changes without tomcat restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Run/Debug configurations* and select *Update classes and resources* for the *On frame deactivation* option.

[image]